# How do make a Page in Django CMS require login?

Tags: django, django-cms

I notice there is a login_required parameter to the Page objects, but there doesn't seem to be any way via the admin to actually set it, and even when I set it via the shell, it doesn't seem to do anything.

How does one create a page with Django CMS that requires the user to be logged in to see it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To use permissions, you have to enable them in your settings. `CMS_PERMISSION = True` You can then set per-page-permissions in the toolbar: *Page->View restrictions*. See [Documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/topics/permissions.html?highlight=permission)